# Autodesk-forge can we open PDF files on viewer

Tags: api, pdf, autodesk-forge, autodesk, autodesk-viewer

We are trying to View following files on Autodesk Forge Viewer in our
application.

1. DWF
2. DWFX
3. DWG
4. DXF
5. NWD
6. RVT
7. NWC
8. PDF
9. RCP
10. GBXML
11. IFC

As per Autodesk documentation
-(https://developer.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/overview/supported-translations/)
these files format are supported to viewer.
But, on (https://viewer.autodesk.com/) this site some files are getting
Format error such as PDF, RCP.

So my questions are:

1. Which file format is supporting to viewer
2. Can we open PDF files on viewer or it require any specific PDF file  to
   launch on viewer.

Answer (score 1):

The files that the Viewer support are in the link you provided from the Model Derivative API. so PDF and RCP are supported. The A360 Viewer does support just to a number of file types, you can see the list from that website here

[image]

As you can see those 2 types are not mentioned there, but it doesn't mean they are not supported from the Forge platform. You will have to use the Model Derivative API in order to translate those file types and use the Viewer API in order to visualize them.